# can maven generate jar including source code

Tags: maven

I try 2 things which were taught by some tutorials :
1. In `maven-source-plugin`:

```xml
<plugin>
          <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
          <artifactId>maven-source-plugin</artifactId>
          <executions>
            <execution>
              <id>attach-sources</id>
              <phase>package</phase>
              <goals>
                <goal>jar-no-fork</goal>
              </goals>
            </execution>
          </executions>
        </plugin>
```

then using cmd:

```
mvn install
```

or

```
mvn source:jar
```

or

```
mvn source:jar-no-fork
```

none of them works.
2. In `maven-jar-plugin`:

```xml
<plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.0.2</version>
          <configuration>
            <includes>
              <include>**/*.java</include>
            </includes>
          </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

none of these methods works.

then how to generate a jar including source code.

Comment: the source plugin should work, did try to set the version of the plugin to `3.0.1`?

Comment: Please note that this request is _very unusual_. The maven source plugin is meant to create an _additional jar_ with the source code. Please follow the standard Maven way unless you have very good reason for something else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To copy the Java source into the main JAR file you can use `resouces:copy-resources`:

```
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>copy-java-sources</id>
                    <phase>prepare-package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>copy-resources</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <outputDirectory>${project.build.outputDirectory}</outputDirectory>
                        <resources>          
                            <resource>
                                <directory>${project.build.sourceDirectory}</directory>
                                <filtering>false</filtering>
                            </resource>
                        </resources>              
                    </configuration>            
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

Please note however that this is not the standard approach to provide Java sources with Maven and should only be used for very special use cases.

The standard approach is to enable the `release-profile`, which uses the `maven-source-plugin` to create a secondary -sources JAR containing only the sources (defined in the [Maven Super POM](https://maven.apache.org/ref/3.6.1/maven-model-builder/super-pom.html)). IDEs can load these sources JAR files and show the sources to the developers.

To activate the `release-profile` as defined in the Maven Super POM you can use:

```
-DperformRelease=true
```

It does not actually perform a release (no version updates or Git tags), but activates some additional goals.

Comment: `<!-- NOTE: The release profile will be removed from future versions of the super POM -->`

Comment: @JFMeier If you like you can copy this profile section to your own parent POM to be future-proof

Comment: Yes, I would add the configuration of the source plugin to my own parent POM.

Comment: thanks a lot.I didn't know jar containing only sources can be load,now I know.I think it's better to use this method.